# How to Avoid a Busy Loop Inside a Function That Returns the Object That's Being Waited For

Tags: anti-patterns, async

I have a function which has the same interface as Python's `input` builtin, but it works in a client-server environment. When it's called, the function, which runs in the server, sends a message to the client, asking it to get some input from the user. The user enters some stuff, or dismisses the prompt, and the result is passed back to the server, which passes it to the function. The function then returns the result.

The function must work like Python's `input` [that's the spec], so it must block until it has the result.

This is all working, but it uses a busy loop, which, in practice, could easily be spinning for many minutes. Currently, the function tells the client to get the input, passing an id. The client returns the result with the id. The server puts the result in a dictionary, with the id as the key. The function basically waits for that key to exist.

```
def input():

    '''simplified example'''

    key = unique_key()
    tell_client_to_get_input(key)
    while key not in dictionary: pass
    return dictionary.pop(pin)
```

Using a callback would be the normal way to go, but the `input` function must block until the result is available, so I can't see how that could work. The spec can't change, as Python will be using the new `input` function for stuff like `help` and `pdb`, which provide their own little REPLs.

I have a lot of flexibility in terms of how everything works overall, but just can't budge on the function acting exactly like Python's.

Is there any way to return the result as soon as it's available, without the busy loop?

Comment: Can you have it return a container object that can later generate a message when the object has been placed in the container? That way, you get an object returned right away.

Comment: It must return the string the user entered. If someone does `help()`, Python will print a message and create a prompt for some input by calling `sys.stdin.readline`. I need to assign a custom `readline` method that blocks and returns the user's input. It's removing the busy loop from that method [or whatever it calls] that's the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want a [semaphore](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/semaphore-objects.html).

```
def input():
    make_network_call()
    sem.acquire()
    return shared_return_value

def callback():
    shared_return_value = whatever
    sem.release()
```

This makes `input()` block on the `acquire()` line until `release()` is called in the callback.  The caller to `input()` isn't aware a callback was involved.  Make sure to initialize the semaphore with a value of zero.

Comment: I went with conditions over semaphores. It just fit the specifics of the problem better, but your answer's spot on. Cheers.